# can I handle & display message for ERROR: ORA-12154 in batch file

Tags: batch-file, oracle11g

I have test.bat batch file in which I am connecting to the different databases.
In test.bat i am executing mysql.sql, and redirect output into result.csv file. But if ERROR:
ORA-12154 occurs it display on command prompt not in csv file I want to display it into the result.csv file.
here is my test.bat :-

```
@ECHO On
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in (D:\batch\InstallList.txt) do (
sqlplus %%b @D:\batch\mysql.sql %%a rem %%b is dbname & password. 
) 
pause;
```

mysql.sql is :-

```
set heading off;
set verify off;
var ename varchar2(20)

exec :ename := '&1'

spool D:\batch\result.csv app
begin
select user_name, user_id from employee where designation = 'manager';
end;
```

I want to show ERROR: ORA-12154 in result.csv.

Comment: I have no way of testing this (which is why it's a comment and not an answer), but assuming Oracle errors come in on StdErr, you should be able to pipe the errors directly to results.csv inside the for loop like this: `sqlplus %%b @D:\batch\mysql.sql %%a 2>>D:\batch\result.csv`

Comment: Its not working somthingDark

Comment: And if you remove the `2`?

Comment: I want only sql output in my result.csv file, if i add this statemnt result contains many things like connected to oracle, sql > smoething .. disconnected ... etc

Comment: i am trying something like SET VAR=FINDSTR "ERROR:" D:\batch\result.csv 
IF NOT [%VAR%]==[] ECHO "ERROR : CAN NOT CONNECT TO DB: %%a "  BUT it gives error:- "ERROR:" was unexpected at this time.